# How does Hogwarts find candidates to attend?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

How does the selection process to attend Hogwarts happen? Do they look at all the residents in the country and find the ones with magic: this seems quite time consuming to me. Do they have a process to narrow down candidates then look more closely?

Comment: DANGIT sowwy i tried to look for duplicates

Comment: Didn't look hard enough :-) There's even a whole section on Pottermore about it; https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-quill-of-acceptance-and-the-book-of-admittance

Comment: ://// really sory

Comment: lol. It's quite hard to think of questions to ask about HP that haven't already been asked. It's one of our top tags

Comment: yah, i try lol.